# performance problem

Tags: c#

OK so I need to know if anyone can see a way to reduce the number of iterations of these loops because I can't. The first while loop is for going through a file, reading one line at a time. The first foreach loop is then comparing each of the compareSet with what was read in the first while loop. Then the next while loop is to do with bit counting.

As requested, an explaination of my algorithm:

There is a file that is too large to fit in memory. It contains a word followed by the pages in a very large document that this word is on. EG:

sky 1 7 9 32....... (it is not in this format, but you get the idea).

so parseLine reads in the line and converts it into a list of ints that are like a bit array where 1 means the word is on the page, and 0 means it isn't.

CompareSet is a bunch of other words. I can't fit my entire list of words into memory so I can only fit a subset of them. This is a bunch of words just like the "sky" example. I then compare each word in compareSet with Sky by seeing if they are on the same page.

So if sky and some other word both have 1 set at a certain index in the bit array (simulated as an int array for performance), they are on the same page. The algorithm therefore counts the occurances of any two words on a particular page. So in the end I will have a list like:

(for all words in list) is on the same page as (for all words in list) x number of times.

eg sky and land is on the same page x number of times.

```
 while ((line = parseLine(s)) != null) {
     getPageList(line.Item2, compareWord);
     foreach (Tuple<int, uint[], List<Tuple<int, int>>> word in compareSet) {
         unchecked {
             for (int i = 0; i < 327395; i++) {
                 if (word.Item2[i] == 0 || compareWord[i] == 0)
                     continue;
                 uint combinedNumber = word.Item2[i] & compareWord[i];
                 while (combinedNumber != 0) {
                     actual++;
                     combinedNumber = combinedNumber & (combinedNumber - 1);
                 }
             }
         }
```

Comment: Can compareSet and compareWord be considered immutable structures for above code?

Comment: is it possible that you see perf hit only after 500 iterations? In that case, you need to revisit your logic - perhaps you can explain it in plain language (as what your are doing) so that others can help you to improve the logic!

Comment: It might be difficult in your case, but try use HashSet or Dictionary whenever possible for lookups. This can potentially eliminate a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my old professor Bud used to say: "When you see nested loops like this, your spidey senses should be goin' CRAZY!"

You have a while with a nested for with another while. This nesting of loops is an exponential increase on the order of operations. Your one for loop has 327395 iterations. Assuming they have the same or similar number of iterations, that means you have an order of operations of

```
327,395 * 327,395 * 327,395 = 35,092,646,987,154,875 (insane)
```

It's no wonder that things would be slowing down. You need to redefine your algorithm to remove these nested loops or combine work somewhere. Even if the numbers are smaller than my assumptions, the nesting of the loops is creating a LOT of operations that are probably unnecessary.

Comment: Yes I know it is performing many iterations of the inner loop, but I have no idea how I can cut this down as it is simply the nature of the task.

Comment: @BobTurbo - Surely the innermost loop logic can be reworked. All it's doing is performing an increment based on a staticly reducing number. If you can adjust the algorithm of that reduction to a single line, you can probably eliminate this loop.

Answer (score 0):

As Joal already mentioned nobody is able to optimize this looping algorithm. But what you can do is trying to better explain what you are trying to accomplish and what your hard requirements are. Maybe you can take a different approach by using some like [`HashSet<T>.IntersectWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb293080.aspx) or `BloomFilter` or something like this.

So if you really want help from here you should not only post the code that doesn't work, but also what the overall task is you like to accomplish. Maybe someone has a completely other idea to solve your problem, making your whole algorithm obsolete.